# How to write $.ajax equivalent for a curl command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, curl

Curl command:

```
curl -u "username:password" -X POST "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token"
```

What I have tried :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token',

        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',      

        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function () {

            alert("Cannot get data");
        }
    });
```

I have tried using dataType: jsonp, contentType: json and other methods but always getting an error response? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: are you sending any data with your request??

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:46887' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: When i use jsonp then the error message in google console is :

GET https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token?callback=jQuery1640197310045363151886_14227355243977&_=14273552444976